# Como fazer um select de um select utilizando o Entity Framework ado.net

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, ado.net

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em **[ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc)** que utiliza como padrão o **[Entity Framework](https://www.asp.net/entity-framework)** para acesso de dados, porém estou necessitando de um **select sobre outro select**, e não sei como fazer isto com o **Entity**.
O código **SQL** que gostaria utilizar é o seguinte:

```
select * from pedidos as p
                 inner join agendamentos as a
                 on a.pedidoID = p.pedidoID
                 where a.data = (select max(data) from (select a.data from pedidos as p
                 inner join agendamentos as a
                 on a.pedidoID = p.pedidoID
                 where a.realizado = 0) as dataagendamentos);
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar, estarei grato!

Comment: Poderia colocar as entidades?

Comment: Poderia explicar qual o intuito desta consulta? Facilitará para a solução do seu problema (pois podem haver outras formas melhores de resolvê-lo).

Comment: A consulta é necessária para listar todos pedidos junto com o último agendamento realizado pelo mesmo.

Comment: @LucasKauer seria um simples
Pedidos 1->n Agendamentos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não deve usar o Entity Framework como SQL porque ele não é SQL. A sentença precisa ser repensada. Deve começar pelos agendamentos incluindo seus pedidos, e não os pedidos incluindo os agendamentos.

Ou seja:

```
var pedidos = db.Agendamentos   
                .Include(a => a.Pedidos)
                .Where(a => a.Realizado == 0)
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.Data)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .SelectMany(a => a.Pedidos)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: O campo **Realizado** está na tabela de **agendamentos**, que possui a chave **pedidosID (FK)** e tambem um **Date** que mostra para quando foi agendado. O que eu preciso fazer é Listar todos os pedidos incluindo o ultimo agendamento **já realizado** e que **não foi pago**.

Comment: Você implementou minha resposta? Se sim, qual o resultado apresentado? Além disso, você editou sua pergunta colocando qual o objetivo da seleção, conforme este comentário que fez na minha resposta?

Comment: Pensando no que você fez eu consegui sucesso com o seguinte código:
 `var pedidos = Db.Agendamentos.Where(m => m.Data < DateTime.Now).Where(m => m.Realizado == false).ToList();
Db.Agendamentos.Include("Pedido").ToList();`

Obrigado!